# Google cloud function triggered by firebase realtime database events

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Apparently some of onCreate/onDelete events our cloud function is triggered by are received more than once!
We've observed them arriving even 3 times a few seconds apart from each other spread between instances of the cloud function. Is it a normal behavior or there is something we've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the content of this "Firebase Google Group" [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/_jYFIvuvLos/wYRBhoCvAQAJ), that I paste below. It was written in August 2018 but is still fully valid at the time of writing this "copy/paste answer".

> Cloud Functions  typically
>   guarantees that your functions are run "at least once", meaning that
>   it's very possible (but typically rare) that an event may get
>   delivered to your function more than once.  To deal with this, your
>   functions should be "idempotent", meaning that the receipt of the same
>   event multiple times should result in no further changes to whatever
>   it is you need to update.  This can be kind of challenging, but it's
>   one of the properties of serverless systems that needs to be dealt
>   with, if it's problematic for your app.
>
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#write_idempotent_functions

Comment: This is fine. What annoys me so much is that it has not been mentioned in any official example on firebase realtime database and cloud functions combination. Moreover, it may not be even solely related to cloud functions behavior but to the nature of the realtime database. We've observed situations when other clients (e.g. Android based) have been receiving same events more than once.